# How (In javascript, Jquery, or Ajax & such) can I load a local text file or xml file into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, load

First, I know `<input type="file" value="c:\\blah.txt">` won't work. I have tried Ajax, and other things, but Google has security, so I can't. How could I possibly load a **local** file in JavaScript (Not PHP)? No, i'm not trying to steal people's data.

Or, if none of this will work, is it possible to pass data from a command prompt to a HTML/JavaScript file/page without a complicated server setup? (The command prompt reads the file, and gives it to the HTML).

#### What I *am not* trying to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.mydomain.com/scriptfile.js">
```

One of my failed tries:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: path,
    dataType: "script",
});
```

I have tried to use the script and text type for both JS and text files, but no luck. I keep getting Google security errors in the console.

#### What I *am* trying to do:

I want to load a file.txt in the "File" format. Lets say I have `var x = /path/to/localfile/text.txt`.

Then, I want to do basically:

```
var x = "c:\\folder\\test.txt";
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: x, //<------
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        //parse the file content here
    }
});
```

Basically, I want to load a file from a variable name, and send the data of the text file to variable y.

But how ever many methods I try, they don't work.

Comment: Where is your ajax tries?

Comment: Are you using local webserver? Because you don't need to supply full path..

Comment: I am just running the html file in a normal google chrome window, so it is local.

Comment: Ajax will not work unless you are using the http protocol, It sounds like you are using the file protocol

Comment: @CyberDude Which browser attempting to load local file with ? Is protocol of local `html` page `file:` ?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.mydomain.com/scriptfile.js">` is NOT what I am trying to do. Just for clarification.

Comment: @CyberDude Which browser attempting to load local file with ?

Comment: Google Chrome. I prefer to not change any settings.

Comment: @Anonymous _"What I AM trying want to do: Load load a file.txt in the "File" format:"_ Not certain this is actual requirement ?

Comment: @guest271314 That was in the question before I edited it.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, you are correct. Perhaps missing something, here; as requirement appear possible - though not without adjusting browser preferences. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135589/how-in-javascript-jquery-or-ajax-such-can-i-load-a-local-text-file-or-xml#comment48381455_30135589 . Perhaps ask OP if this is also part of requirement ; i.e.g., to _not_ change any browser settings ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, you should ask the OP if you're unsure.

Comment: @CyberDude Is requirement to a) access local files utilizing `file:` protocol , `$.ajax("local/file")` ? b) _not_ adjust browser settings to implement a) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible, for now. If you want to load local file in web project you can use java applet. 
Javascript gives access only to cookies and web storage.

Comment: _"This is impossible, for now."_ ? Can be achieved at chrome , chromium by adjusting launch flags

Comment: This is a "hack". It is posible to load local file in script tag (